# Why in op-amp inverting circuits one of the op-amp inputs is grounded?

Tags: operational-amplifier, inverting-amplifier

[image: inverting amplifier]Why the input have to be grounded in Op-amps? What does it do? How does op-amp sense the input voltage difference?

Comment: Your question is based on a falsehood.

Comment: Maybe show some example schematics that are confusing you and we can explain how they work.

Comment: what do you mean it is falsehood? please elaborate, I am totally new to op-amp

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/alYMh0T.png

Comment: Do not mix between protective earth and ground. In your case it is just common wire and very often It is called "ground".

Comment: Just rephrase your question so that it doesn’t rely on asserting anything that might be false i.e. ask a question.

Comment: Please do some reading up on op-amps and then come back with a revised question. You won't be in a position to fully understand any answers given without a basic   understanding of the principles involved.

Comment: Your observation that in most op-amp application circuits one of the op-amp inputs is grounded is true and your implicit question as to why this is so is logical. It only remains to find a convincing answer to it... *(It would be good for more of us here to ask such questions and try to answer them instead of suppressing them.)*

Comment: Well, short answer is: it doesn't have to be grounded. It's connection totally depends on the application circuit, just like it does for any other electronic part. There're good articles online that discuss basic opamp topics, like this one: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_1.html

Comment: @kutukvpavel, This is hardly the place where OP will find an answer to the question. One of the comments below the article: "You aren’t good at explaining this whatsoever, nothing in this article does more than leave me asking why."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why the input have to be grounded in Op-amps?

You probably mean, "Why does the op-amp non-inverting input is grounded in the circuit of *inverting amplifier*?"

My short answer is:  **Because it is not necessary in this case**. Let's see why...

### Op-amp stage

First of all, you have to distinguish between "op-amp" and "op-amp inverting amplifier". The former is a component while the latter is a circuit implemented with this component and two more resistors.

This circuit does not need an op-amp with a sophisticated *differential input*; it needs only an op-amp with a humble *single-ended input*. But nowadays there are no such simple op-amps; that is why the unused non-inverting input is connected to ground.

The differential input is created for the purposes of the dual *noninverting ampifier* circuit with negative feedback. There it allows the input and output voltages to be subtracted from each other in a series manner, without a need of any resistors for this purpose (they serve for snother purpose - attenuation). The resulting voltage is "floating"; hence the need of a differential input.

Here this subtraction is implemented in a parallel manner by the summing network of two resistors Rin and Rf in series  (Vin and Vout are actually subtracted since they always have opposite polarities). The resulting voltage is referenced to ground; so it can be applied to the single inverting input.

So, in this op-amp circuit with negative feedback, the op-amp is driven from the side of the inverting input; that is why the circuit is inverting. The unused non-inverting input is fixed (usually grounded). Another example of such circuit but without negative feedback can be an *inverting op-amp comparator*.

In some circuits with positive feedback (e.g., a *non-inverting Schmitt trigger*), the op-amp is driven from the side of the non-inverting input; that is why the circuit is non-inverting. Here the unused inverting input is fixed (grounded). Another example of such circuit but without positive feedback can be a *non-inverting op-amp comparator*.

### Transistor stage

The same idea can be seen in the basic amplifier transistor stages where the transistor can be thought of as an amplifier device with a differential input - the base-emitter junction, driven by two voltages referenced to ground. The resulting base-emitter voltage is "floating".

In the common-emitter amplifier, the transistor is driven from the side of the base and the emitter voltage is fixed.

In the common-base amplifier, the transistor is driven from the side of the emitter and the base voltage is fixed.

### Bridge circuit

You can see the same idea even in the 19-century bridge circuit where a 2-terminal floating bridge element (galvanometer, motor, etc.) is driven by two voltages referenced to ground and "produced" by two voltage dividers.

You can vary the left voltage while keeping the right voltage fixed and v.v., you can vary the right voltage while keeping the left voltage fixed. Thus you can reverse the voltage across the bridge element.

### Generalization

The common idea behind these specific (op-amp, transistor and electrical) circuits can be explained as follows.

Two voltage sources are connected in series and the middle point is grounded. They have the same polarity in regards to ground; so their voltages Vin1 and Vin2 are subtracted according to KVL. They are grounded but the resulting voltage Vout = Vin1 - Vin2 is floating.

If you zero Vin2, Vout = Vin1; if you zero Vin1, Vout = -Vin2. So you can make this arrangement non-inverting or inverting.

Answer (score 2):

The circuit you show is called an inverting amplifier.

The non-inverting input is grounded in this topology to the same ground as the input signal.

An op-amp has very large gain, so any voltage differential on the inputs will cause the output voltage to change so as to minimize the input voltage differential due to the feedback provided by Rf.

That will drive the difference between the + and - inputs to very close to zero.

So the input voltage almost entirely appears across Rin, causing a current of Vin/Rin to flow in Rin.  That current almost entirely flows through Rf, since an op-amp's inputs are very high impedance.

That leads to the output voltage being -Vin/Rin*Rf.

Other topologies do not have one of the inputs grounded.  For example a non-inverting amplifier or a differential amplifier.  (Google will show you lots of examples.)

Answer (score 2):

The input does not have to be grounded. But since the input and output voltages are ground-referenced, it makes sense to use the same reference for the op-amp too, be it ground or any other voltage. It simply makes ground as the DC zero voltage bias to which the input and output voltages are measured (referenced), and since this is an inverting op-amp circuit, the output will be input multiplied with some negative number.

An op-amp senses the input voltage difference with a differential amplifier. These days op-amps are solid-state devices, ICs that have integrated transistors connected as differential amplifier. You can also build a differential amplifier with discrete transistors. Back in the 1940s operational amplifiers were made with electronic valves (vacuum tubes).

Answer (score 1):

An op-amp has *two* inputs: inverting and non-inverting. The inputs feed a *differential amplifier* that strongly amplifies any *voltage difference* between them. Why? This 2-input differential topology is useful and flexible for making both differential and single-ended circuits. In fact, the 2-input op-amp is so useful, it has proven to be a cornerstone of modern analog design.

The example you show is a single-ended inverting amplifier. This requires that the (+) input be tied to a reference, in this case, ground. Because of the *negative feedback* Rf, the (-) input will also be very close to the (+) input voltage due to the amplification and feedback. This is called *virtual ground*, and it's possible due to the op-amp high gain (in the 10,000 range for most typical amps.)

In simple terms, with the inverting feedback shown, the op-amp tries very, very hard to make the two inputs the *same voltage*. This is how we can say that, for the inverting op-amp, the gain is:

- Vout = -Vin*(Rf / Rin)

How do we know this? With the (+) at GND, and we also know that (-) is at virtual ground. Another thing we know is that the op-amp input currents are very, very low - low enough that for most purposes they can be treated as infinite impedance.

Taking all this together, let's look at what the resistor currents are doing then:

- I(Rin) = (Vin - GND)/Rin =  Vin/Rin: Current into (-) virtual ground
- I(Rf) =  (GND - Vout)/Rf = -Vout/Rf: Current out of (-) virtual ground

We know that the current into and out of the (-) input must be equal (that is, their net sum is zero.) So we know that:

- I(Rin) + I(Rf) = 0

or:

- I(Rin) = -I(Rf)

Substituting from above:

- Vin/Rin = -Vout/Rf

Rearranging, flipping sign, we get:

- Vout = -Vin*(Rf/Rin)

as above.

There are specialty amplifiers that have only one input, but these are less common. These aren't considered 'op-amps' and are usually reserved for specific functions, like signal buffering or conditioning.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend starting here: [Eevblog's video on op amps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FYHt5XviKc). You can find the questions to your answers just by googling "[Virtual ground op amp](https://electrosome.com/virtual-ground-opamp/)".

There is a ton of material out there regarding your question :)